# Chrome extension V3 Cannot read properties of undefined setBadgeBackgroundColor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a V3 Chrome Extension work, but I'm not sure how to change this V2 code that works.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Extension name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "Display API Info.",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "./icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "./icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "./icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "action": {}
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "green" });

const setStuff = () => {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: `...` });
}

const callApi = () => {
    setStuff();

    setTimeout(() => fetch('https://api.com/api')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: `${data.info}` });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error)), 5000)

}

callApi()

setInterval(function () {
    callApi()
}, 300000);
```

Getting this error when testing it locally

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setBadgeBackgroundColor')
```

Comment: There's no browserAction in MV3, only `action`, see the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: @wOxxOm can you please add an answer?

Answer (score 8):

Change your code that is manifest v2:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "green" });

const setStuff = () => {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: `...` });
}
```

To this code for Chrome extension manifest v3:

```
chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "green" });

const setStuff = () => {
    chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: `...` });
}
```